# select dropdownlist value and display gridview from different tables ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I create web application. I add drop down list. I connect list with Names of Tables Categories. for example 1, 2, 3. When I select value 1 it should be created grid view populated with data from Table 1. When I select 2 create grid view populated with data from Table 2.. 
I connect tables in the SQL database. PrimaryKey Category ID, foreign key1, foreign key2 approprietly.

I know how to populate grid view by select value in the drop down list, but the values from one table. In this case I have 4 tables and I don't know how to realise that. Is there somebody who can help me? by some tutorial, or piece of code? thanks

Comment: You either use 4 GridViews which are all `Visible="false"` (except one) or you set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` and bind the DataSource(f.e. a DataTable) dynamically in DropDownList's `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.

Comment: I was thinking to realize by Visible property, but I thing shouldn't be good solution. Could you help me how to create by binding Data Source dynamically?

Comment: Visible=false actually **is** a good approach since server-controls won't be rendered at all on clientside if they are not visible on serverside. It's the easiest and most robust approach all the more if you want to use TemplateFields in your GridView(s). _[sorry, need to go to bed now]_

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, even if visible is false, won't that still cause the database being accessed?

Comment: @RayCheng: No, only if you databind the grid. You could have a `switch-statement` for every DropDownList value and switch the visibility of each GridView. And only the visible grid gets databound.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

aspx page:

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDb" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDb_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select --" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Students" Value="Students"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Classes" Value="Classes"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void ddlDb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlDb.SelectedValue))
    {
        var dbPath = Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data\Database1.mdf");
        var scon = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='" + dbPath + "';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        var cmd = "select * from " + ddlDb.SelectedValue;

        var dt = new DataTable();
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, scon);
        da.Fill(dt);

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();                
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ray Cheng thank you very much, you understand my problem and find elegant solution for it. I couldn't solve my problem, but now works great.